# Use wildcard in SQL table entry

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, wildcard

I have been looking around for such a solution, but no positive results so far...
My **table** consists of entries **data**, like

1. 1234
2. 3241
3. 8424
4. 8_24
5. 9_13
6. 8_2_
7. 8_25

where '_' are wildcards which can be from 0-9.
I'd like to find a way to retrieve these data, like:
SELECT * from table WHERE data LIKE '8424', the query should return both 8424 and 8_24.

Thank you in advance!

PS. The point is, A **data** like '8_24' can be understood as '8024' or '8124' or '8224', etc.,
so does the 6th row.
Therefore, If I the query is SELECT * from table WHERE data LIKE '8424', it should return the 4th and 6th row. If I use SELECT * from table WHERE data LIKE '8_2_', the 7th row will be included, which is not what I want.

Finally,
**I found the solution. It's extremely simple, just use:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE '8424' LIKE data
Thank you all for your answers!**

Comment: If it's a string and you can use Like, are you just looking to '%'. [SQL Like via W3](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) or are you trying to be more specific like single numeric, etc.?

Comment: Hi. I'd like to look any character. But for simplicity, just numeric in this case. The point is, I want to not only use wildcard in the query but the data entries also. In the table, if there's another data like '8_2_', it should also be included in the return results.

Comment: You can also use as described in the answers for Like something with [0-9].

Comment: you should mark the proper answer as the answer, or make your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data LIKE '8%24'
```

That would also pull in things like '834434224' though...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data LIKE '8_24'
```

This uses a single character wildcard (_) and would work.

[LIKE Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Comment: I understand, but it'd not return the data like 8_2_, if any. That's the problem...

Comment: So you're storing the wildcards in the database and want to retrieve them when searching for a number like 8424? Vineet's answer may work.

Comment: Finally, I found the solution. It's extremely simple, just use: SELECT * FROM table WHERE '8424' LIKE data. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where data like '8[4_]24'
```

See the "pattern" section in the documentation for [LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712968/use-wildcard-in-sql-table-entry/10713072#10713072).  You can use `[]` to specify a range or set of characters.

Comment: Finally, I found the solution. It's extremely simple, just use: SELECT * FROM table WHERE '8424' LIKE data. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Select * from table where data =substr('8424',0,instr(data,'*'))|| substr('8424',instr(data,'*'),length(data));

This will ensure for single wild card entry

Else try

Select * from table where replace(data,'_','%') like '8424';

Comment: Thank you. I tried, but it does not work. I think the '_' and '%' in data is understood as normal characters, not wildcards. So it does not match the criteria...

Comment: Finally, I found the solution. It's extremely simple, just use: SELECT * FROM table WHERE '8424' LIKE data.  Thank you!

Comment: @johnWhite: Oops, didn't see your comments until after I pressed `Submit` on my answer. Please consider posting your find as an answer (and accepting it).